# How do I open a config file that is located in a folder not with the main file?

Tags: go

I want to add a configuration to my project and i have such a project structure:

```
app:
  -cmd
    - main
       -app.go
  -internal
    - config
        -config.go
  -pkg
  config.yaml
  go.mod
  go.sum
```

In the config file, I want to read config.yaml:

```
func GetConfig() *Config {
    once.Do(func() {
        instance = &Config{}
        logger := logging.GetLogger("info")
        logger.Info("start config initialisation")
        if err := cleanenv.ReadConfig("config.yaml", instance); err != nil {
            help, _ := cleanenv.GetDescription(instance, nil)
            logger.Info(help)
            logger.Fatal(err)
        }

    })
    return instance
}
```

And I get an error: **system cannot find the file specified**.
And to fix it, I need to move the configuration file to the folder where the application is launched, that is, to **cmd/main**
And I wonder if it is possible to fix it somehow so that the file lies together with the initialization of the project along with **go.mod** and so on.I tried to specify different paths in the place of reading the file, but nothing worked.

*I use the cleanenv library for reading*

Comment: Paths are relative to the [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), not the location of a source file or executable.  If you want to distribute the file with the executable, then [embed](https://godoc.org/embed) the file in the executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wd,err := os.Getwd()
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
parentTop := filepath.Dir(wd) // if your working directory is top level you can skip this step
// and wd instead
```

then use the parent and `parentTop +"/pkg/config.yaml"`